# Algebraic solutions to a set of data points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, functions

I couldn't find much on this anywhere (probably because I don't know where to look :P).I am wondering, given two points on a plane, is it true that an infinite number of functions of the form: $ax^b + cx^d + dx^e +… $(where everything can be a variable) will exist, which will serve as exact intercepts to these points? Could this be? Obviously for 1 point, this would be true, but for two points as well?

Additionally, if it's not too much, what would be the story for three points (if we constrained ourselves to power functions, I guess there would only be one possible function, but what about a function of the previous unrestrained form ($ax^b + cx^d + …$)?).

By the way, I am only considering it all in terms of exact solutions, i.e. no approximative functions!

Sorry if my question comes off as a bit brutish, but I am still, more or less, a noob at math :P…

Comment: If you have $n$ points (all with different $x$-coordinate) in the plane, there is exactly one polynomial of degree $n-1$ which intercepts those points. There are infinitely many polynomials which intercept the points if you allow their degree to be greater than $n-1$.

Comment: But wouldn't that imply that a quadratic can have 3 real roots? Or do you mean degree n + 1?

Comment: Sorry I must have forgotten a condition. The degree of the polynomial described is *at most* of degree $n-1$, and so in your example a degree $0$ polynomial (ie a horizontal line) fits the points. A good place to read would be this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolation_polynomial